# UiTimer runs infinitely even if the repeat boolean is false

Tags: codenameone

What I want to do here is that if there is no network, I have a timer to check if the network is connected or not for every 2 min. So initially I've repeat boolean true and it loops infinitely until the network is connected. As soon as the network is connected, I've a connectionRequest and then set repeat flag to false. But while debugging, I found out that although the network has been connected and the repeat flag is set to false, the timer runs infinitely. Why is that?

```
if (!Connectivity.isConnected()) {
    Log.p("tracking5 " + "net not connected");
    repeatFlag = true;
    new UITimer(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (Connectivity.isConnected()) {
                c.liveTrackConnectionMethod(latitude + "", longitude + "");
                repeatFlag = false;
                Log.p("tracking6 " + "net connected AND gps data sent within 2 min");
            }
            Log.p("tracking8 " + repeatFlag + "repeatFlag");
        }

    }).schedule(120000, repeatFlag, Home.this);
}else {
    - - - - - - - - 
    - - - - - - - - 
}
```

Comment: Never used CodenameOne, but looking at the docs I think you need to call cancel() on the UITimer. Setting repeatFlag won't affect the schedule which has already been set to repeat.

Comment: Awww Thankyou @Bemmu.

Answer (score 0):

The repeat flag is set to `true`. Notice that if you change it after invoking `schedule` it will have no impact.